# Is there a way to map over a child component and a parent component in React, I am getting strange results

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React, and have started with the Tic Tak Toe tutorial within the React docs.

I am trying to create 3 `boardRows` and 3 columns wide of `squareButtons`.

Please let me know if what I am trying to do is a normal thing, and also if there are better ways of doing it/approaching it.

I would be very grateful, thank you

This is what this code is returning, and below is my code:
[image: Incorrect numbering]

```
import {useState} from "react";

export default function Board() {
    let buttonId = 1;
    let boardRowIndex = 0;

    function SquareButton({ id }) {
        return <button className="square">{id}</button>;
    }
    
    function BoardRow() {
        const squareButtons = [...Array(3).keys()].map(() => {
            const squareButton = <SquareButton key={buttonId - 1} id={buttonId} />;
            
            buttonId++;
            
            return squareButton;
        });
        
        return (
            <div className="board-row">
                { squareButtons }
            </div>
        );
    }
    
    const boardRows = [...Array(3).keys()].map(() => {
        const boardRow = <BoardRow key={boardRowIndex}/>;

        boardRowIndex++;

        return boardRow;
    });
        
    
    // The first squareButton begins at 4 now for some reason, and then skipping out numbers that aren't being displayed
    return (
        <>
            { boardRows }
        </>
    );
}
```

I have tried debugging in devtools, and this line

```
const boardRows = [...Array(3).keys()].map(() => {
```

seems to get hit 2 times.

I am not sure why, but perhaps due to a re-render?

It is supposed to be 3 rows by 3 columns, but the numbering should be 1 - 9.

Thank you

Comment: you buttonId is same and probably that is causing some issue. create sperate `buttonID` and try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`buttonId` and `boardRowIndex` for all the buttons and rows are sam here. When you increment `buttonId` in one row, it affects the numbering in the another rows.

Try to create a method which create id for you `createId` maintain separate buttonId values for each row and calculate the id values accordingly.

Try below code.

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Board() {
  const generateBoard = () => {
    const board = new Array(3).fill(null).map(() => new Array(3).fill(null));
    let currentId = 1;

    return board.map((row) =>
      row.map(() => {
        const id = currentId++;
        return { id, number: id };
      })
    );
  };

  const initialBoard = generateBoard();

  const SquareButton = ({ id, number }) => {
    return <button className="square">{number}</button>;
  };

  const BoardRow = ({ rowButtons }) => {
    const squareButtons = rowButtons.map(({ id, number }) => {
      return <SquareButton key={id} id={id} number={number} />;
    });

    return (
      <div className="board-row">
        {squareButtons}
      </div>
    );
  };

  const boardRows = initialBoard.map((rowButtons, rowIndex) => {
    return <BoardRow key={rowIndex} rowButtons={rowButtons} />;
  });

  return (
    <>
      {boardRows}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, unfortunately it still hasn't solved my issue and because there are multiple `BoardRow`'s, and the `rowIds` that are being passed through are the same on the 3 iterations of the BoardRow, the key for `<SquareButton />` has three identical keys. I also want to display a number in each of the `SquareButton`'s, but I cannot do this unless I have a count of some sort outside of the map scope.

Comment: @LukeBennett this part i didn't got initally. I have  updated the code. please check. only code I have updated.

Comment: Ah perfect, that works! I'll study it so I don't make the same mistake again, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @LukeBennett great !! you can accept as answer if it works.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting strange results when mapping over a child component and a parent component in React is because you are recreating the child component on every render of the parent component. This is because you are using the key prop to generate a unique key for each child component, but you are not passing the id prop to the child component.

To fix this, you can pass the id prop from the parent component to the child component using the key prop. This will ensure that the child component is only recreated when the id prop changes.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Board() {
  let buttonId = 1;
  let boardRowIndex = 0;

  function SquareButton({ id }) {
    return <button className="square">{id}</button>;
  }

  function BoardRow() {
    const squareButtons = [...Array(3).keys()].map((i) => {
      const squareButton = <SquareButton key={i} id={buttonId} />;

      buttonId++;

      return squareButton;
    });

    return (
      <div className="board-row">
        {squareButtons}
      </div>
    );
  }

  const boardRows = [...Array(3).keys()].map((i) => {
    const boardRow = <BoardRow key={i} />;

    return boardRow;
  });

  // The first squareButton begins at 4 now for some reason, and then skipping out numbers that aren't being displayed
  return (
    <>
      {boardRows}
    </>
  );
}
```

There are a few other ways to approach this problem. One way is to use a state management library like Redux to manage the state of the board. This would allow you to keep track of the id and other state of the board in a centralized location, and to update the state of the board without having to re-render the entire component tree.

Another way to approach this problem is to use a virtual DOM library like React Fiber. React Fiber allows you to update the DOM without having to re-render the entire component tree. This can make your application faster and more responsive.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I have tried this however, and it seems to be producing the same results as the code I had previously used. This line `const boardRows = [...Array(3).keys()].map((i) => {` seems to be hit multiple times still, I'm not sure what is causing it.